# PHP mkdir or chmod 0777 doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, permissions, mkdir

I have a small script that create a directory for a user who registers an account on my site. This director is used to store images in that they upload.

When I use `mkdir()` with permissions of 0777, the directory is created under the users name, but the permissions stay as 0755.

I have tried a few different ways to do this, as follows;

```
$path = path/to/directory/and/filename

$old = umask(0);
mkdir($path,0777);
umask($old);
```

also;

```
$path = path/to/directory/and/filename/

mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

also;

```
$path = path/to/directory/and/filename/

mkdir($path);
chmod($path,0777);
```

When I create a directory myself in the ftp client the owner and group is me, but when the php script created them, it has the owner and group of `apache/apache'`. I don't think if this is anything to do with it?

I have spent a good while trying to figure this out, and I have also spent a fair amount of time searching on this forum and others, so any help would be amazing!

If there is any other information required, I can provide. Thanks!

Comment: have you try to create a folder or file?

Comment: @saty a folder. Created a folder using PHP has no issues, but giving the folder permissions of 0777 is the issue

Comment: try exec("chmod -R 777 $foldername");

Comment: @saty 's answer worked in the end. It was also a case of my forgetful memory, calling an action which I wasnt actually still using and forgot to remove. This is now solved. Thanks.

Comment: thanks can i put under answer so other people can use it also